# Rails install fails: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a new Rails app. I am using rvm with ruby-2.1.2. I am usint the `@global` gemset and plan to use bundler to manage gem dependencies. However, `gem install rails` fails:

```
$ gem install rails
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.0.3.pre3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.0.3.pre3
Fetching: minitest-5.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed minitest-5.9.0
Fetching: thread_safe-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed thread_safe-0.3.5
Fetching: tzinfo-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed tzinfo-1.2.2
Fetching: i18n-0.7.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.7.0
Fetching: activesupport-5.0.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

Yes, it is true I am using ruby-2.1.2 and not ruby-2.2.2, but shouldn't I still be allowed to use ruby-2.1.2? Are we not allowed to use ruby-2.1.2 anymore?

I thought maybe that ActiveSupport 5 was already installed in the `@global` gemset and that ActiveSupport 5 required 2.2.2, but actually there is no ActiveSupport 5 in the `@global` gemset:

```
$ rvm gemdir
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
$ cd /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
$ cd gems
$ ls
bundler-unload-1.0.2        gem-wrappers-1.2.4      rake-10.1.0         rvm-1.11.3.9            tzinfo-1.2.2
concurrent-ruby-1.0.3.pre3  i18n-0.7.0          rdoc-4.1.0          test-unit-2.1.2.0
executable-hooks-1.3.2      minitest-5.9.0          rubygems-bundler-1.4.4      thread_safe-0.3.5
```

So how can I prevent this error from occurring while trying to use ruby-2.1.2?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You're allowed to use any ruby version of your will, however you can't use any ruby version with the latest version of Rails.
When you do `gem install rails` you're getting the latest Rails' version (Rails 5), which isn't compatible with Ruby 2.1.2 at all.

If you really want to use Ruby 2.1.2, try this: `gem install rails -v 4.2.2`. You can find ruby and rails version compatibility [here](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) and possible rails version [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions)

As the use of gemset, since I like this pretty organized, I never use the global. I always create a new gemset for every project. This guarantee that I can have many projects, each one with a ruby and rails version, without getting any incompatibility between the gems. This of gemset as your Ruby on Rails workspace. If you separate them by project, you will minimize the odds of oddities with gem incompatibility.

Comment: Your first point answers my question. However, your second point I have to disagree with. Every time you create a new gemset you will have duplicate copies of gems that are similar for each project. The whole purpose of bundler is to resolve dependency issues and use the Gemfile to load the right gems, so oddities with gem incompatibilities will never happen.

Comment: @Donato that doesn't came out of my mind randomly. And it wasn't my wish.
You can read the specifications from the most trustable source: https://rvm.io/gemsets/basics
From the 'Warning!' session:
"RVM gives you a separate gem directory for each and every Ruby version and gemset. * This means that gems must be explicitly installed for each revision and gemset. RVM helps you manage this process; see the RVM set documentation page."

Comment: Duplicate gems for different projects on your system are free. Flexibility and sanity are quite a bit more valuable.

Comment: No longer works in 2020 because other dependencies seem to have required ruby 2.5+

Comment: You can find ruby and rails version compatibility here:https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html
And possible rails version here: https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions

Answer (score 8):

```
gem install rails
```

Above command will use latest version of rails, that is stable release of Rails 5, which require >= ruby 2.2.2.

We can use 2.1.2 with lower version of Rails. Please specify version at the time of installing rails may solve your issue, For Example:

```
gem install rails --version 4.2.4
```

or

```
gem install rails -v 4.2.4
```

Let me know if it works.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I faced it fore CocoaPod and it fixes by the following:

1. sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
2. sudo gem install cocoapods

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5603

Answer (score 1):

Using RVM worked for me, I've followed instructions [here](http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-2-2-on-centos-rhel/)

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import - &&\
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable &&\
source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh && /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm reload &&\
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm requirements run &&\
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 2.2.4 &&\
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm use 2.2.4 --default && ruby --version
```

My environment was a Docker container with CentOS installed

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ***rbenv***

Please verify that rbenv is properly set up using this rbenv-doctor script:

```
$ curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails version should be compatible with installed Ruby version. When you do gem install rails you're getting the latest Rails' version (Rails 5), which isn't compatible with Ruby 2.1.2 at all.

If you really want to use Ruby 2.1.2, try this: gem install rails -v 4.2.2. You can find ruby and rails version compatibility [here](https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html) and possible rails version [here](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions).